# how to print a number triangle in java

Tags: java

I need to produce a triangle as shown:

```
    1
   22
  333
 4444
55555
```

and my code is:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)  
    {          
        System.out.print(i); 
    }      
    System.out.print("\n");        
}
```

Producing a triangle the opposite way

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

What do i need to do to my code to make it face the right way?

Comment: I'd say print some spaces. Can you think of a relation between the number of spaces you need and `i`?

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 for loops:

1. Upper-level loop for the actual number to be repeated and printed
2. first inner level for printing the spaces
3. second inner level for to print the number repeatedly
4. at the end of the Upper-level loop print new line

Code:

```
public void printReversedTriangle(int num)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=num; i++)
    {
        for(int j=num-i; j>0; j--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int z=0; z<i; z++)
        {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
     1
    22
   333
  4444
 55555
666666
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem in my AP CS class. I think you may be starting to learn how to program so heres what I'd do without giving you the answer.

Use a loop which removes the number of spaces each iteration. The first time through you would want to print four spaces then print 1 one time(probably done in a separate loop). 
Next time through one less space, but print i one more time.

Comment: May you please explain this to me because I would really like to understand what to do if i ever come across this situation again?

Comment: Well the idea here is not the answer, its how you go about getting it. The first thing I'd do is look at the output and try to find any correlations. Then try to write some code based on the relations I find. In this problem you can see that the amount of spaces decrements each iteration, and the number of times i is printed increments by one each time.

Comment: Yes, can you explain how I could get to my answer because I don't really understand the entire concept of loops in general.

Comment: If you look above to Brian's code, you can see he has a main loop, which controls how many lines of output are printed in this case there are 5. Where it says "// Determine number of spaces needed" You would use a nested loop to print 5 - i spaces, then your second nested loop to print j i amount of times. If you are having trouble with loops in general I would advise you to look in your book if you have one and read a chapter, or look for videos on YouTube. Once you get the problem solved run through debug and track your variables to gain a deeper understanding of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print some spaces. There is a relation between the number of spaces you need and the number (`i`) you're printing. You can print X number of spaces using :

```
for (int k = 0; k < numSpaces; k++)
{
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

So in your code:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    // Determine number of spaces needed
    // print spaces
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)  
    {          
        System.out.print(i); 
    }      
    System.out.print("\n");        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code ,

```
int i, j,z;
            boolean repeat = false;
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                repeat = true;
                for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    if(repeat){
                        z = i;
                        repeat = false;
                        while(z<5){
                        System.out.print(" ");
                        z++;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print(i);
                }

                {
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
```

Comment: I feel that this is overly complicated, might get the job done but not the most intuitive.

Comment: There is nothing complicated in this code.I just use one while loop and one Boolean variable.very basic java

Comment: It's not a very robust solution. What if he want's to print 6 lines now?

Comment: just use 6 instead of 5. you can use this code portion inside the method and pass number of lines as parameter.   as example:   private void createNumberTriangle(int numberOfLines){} , just replace 5 with   "numberOfLines"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
int i, j;
int size = 5;
for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    if (i < size) System.out.printf("%"+(size-i)+"s", " ");
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

This line:
    `if (i < size) System.out.printf("%"+(size-i)+"s", " ");`

Is going to print the left spaces.

It uses the old `printf` with a fixed sized string like 5 characters: `%5s`

Try it here: http://ideone.com/jAQk67

Answer (score 0):

i'm having trouble sometimes as well when it's about formatting on console...
...i usually extract that problem into a separate method...

all about how to create the numbers and spacing has been posted already, so this might be overkill ^^

```
/**
* creates a String of the inputted number with leading spaces
* @param number the number to be formatted
* @param length the length of the returned string
* @return a String of the number with the size length 
*/
static String formatNumber(int number, int length){

    String numberFormatted = ""+number; //start with the number
    do{
        numberFormatted = " "+numberFormatted; //add spaces in front of
    }while(numberFormatted.length()<length);   //until it reaches desired length

    return formattedNumber;
}
```

that example can be easily modified to be used even for Strings or whatever ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use three loops and it will produce your required output:

```
    for (int i=1;i<6 ;i++ )
    {
        for(int j=5;j>i;j--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
        {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not produce the opposite, because the opposite would mean that you have spaces but on the right side. The right side of your output is simply empty, making you think you have the opposite. You need to include spaces in order to form the shape you want.

Try this:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        for(int line = 1; line <= 5; line++){
            //i decreases with every loop since number of spaces
            //is decreasing
            for(int i =-1*line +5; i>=1; i--){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            //j increases with every loop since number of numbers
            //is decreasing
            for(int j = 1; j <= line; j++){
                System.out.print(line);
            }
            //End of loop, start a new line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

You approached the problem correctly, by starting with the number of lines. Next you have to make a relation between the number of lines (the first for loop) and the for loops inside. When you want to do that remember this formula:

**Rate of change*line + X = number of elements on line**

You calculate rate of change by seeing how the number of elements change after each line. For example on the first line you have 4 spaces, on the second line you have 3 spaces. You do 3 - 4 = -1, in other words with each line you move to, the number of spaces is decreasing by 1. Now pick a line, let's say second line. By using the formula you will have

-1(rate of change) * 2(line) + X = 3(how many spaces you have on the line you picked).

You get X = 5, and there you go you have your formula which you can use in your code as you can see on line 4 in the for loop.

> for(int i = **-1 * line +5**; i >= 1; i--)

You do the same for the amount of numbers on each line, but since rate of change is 1 i.e with every line the amount of numbers is increasing by 1, X will be 0 since the number of elements is equal to the line number.

> for(int j = 1; **j <= line**; j++){